# Can I use Series Fill in Excel to generate a long Text Series?

Tags: excel, fill, series, autofill

I was using excel and I need to generate a Series which goes:
Ret 1
Ret 2
Ret 3

So on till...

Ret 15000

I've been able to drag it reasonably till 100 or so, but it's impossible to do it till 15000. I've solved the problem using a different approach, but wanted to know if this was possible using JUST the Fill function in Excel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your value starts at `A1` you can use `="Ret "&ROW(A1)` and fill it down to `A15000`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Already knew this. My question was more along whether the fill feature could be used for this in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a round about way, but surely works.

- Enter '1' in column A (A1)
- Select column A and click Home --> Fill --> Series
- Type --> Linear, Stop value --> 15000 and click OK
- Enter 'Ret 1' in column B (B1)
- Double click the fill handle in the cell B1.

Now you have what you wanted

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Already knew this. My question was more along whether the fill feature could be used for this in some way

Comment: @RahulSethi . unfortunately this wont work for strings, other that dragging it